# How to load image on scene in another way? JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I can load image. It doesn't display. What is wrong?
I am looking for a solution.
I have checked another questions but I have no found a proper way to do it.

```
 public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Sho.setDefaultSettings();

        Pane root = new Pane();

        root.getChildren().add(Sho.startPane);
        root.getChildren().add(Sho.viewerPane);
        Sho.viewPane(Sho.startPane);


        //Creating an image
        Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream("C:\\img.png"));

        //Setting the image view 1
        ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(image);
```

Comment: I don't know much about JavaFX, but I'd say you need to add the `ImageView` object to `root`.

Comment: [mcve] that demonstrates what you are after and how it doesn't work as expected, please .. (nobody wants to wade through tons of unrelated code ..)

Comment: I pasted all my code. It is basic, simple and no to long code anyway.

Comment: @kleopatra is right, as we don't know what the class `Sho` is about, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding the imageView to the root Pane's children. 
You need to do this :

```
root.getChildren().add(imageView1);
```